# What can I use MATLAB function "Plot3D"?

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

I'am a beginner for using MATLAB. I have a question. 
The function

```
f(x; y) = x^2 - 4x + y^2 - y - xy
```

has a local minimum at `f(3; 2) = -7`. 
Using MATLAB function `Plot3D`, plot the surface `z = f(x; y)` for `x \in [2:5; 3:5]` and `y \in
[1:5; 2:5].`

Comment: Do you read description of plot3D function from Matlab help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the "mesh" is the one that will do for you. 
See the documentation for this for more, but you can try:

x=linspace(....);y=...

[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);

z= x^2 - 4*x + y^2 - y - x.*y

mesh(x,y,z)